# can magnet used in engines

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, magnetostatics

My friend has told an idea that if the same poled magnets are placed in the motors instead of engines,it will produce the ultimate energy.because same poles are repelling each other.  is it possible?

Comment: Do you have an example of the idea of a setup, where something would run around (or in another way perform like an engine) purely by magnetic repelling forces?

Comment: A sidenote: Watch out with the term "same poled magnets". A magnet can never have just one pole.

Comment: yes. we have two strong magnets . one at bottom another at top.we connect these magnets with chain.so by inducting small amount of work, by means of external force, the top magnet forced to move down, same time the bottom magnet pulls that towards the top.by these we can move the wheel..this is our idea

Comment: `same time the bottom magnet pulls that towards the top` Pulls what towards the top? Would you have a drawing?